# Update to Windows 10 with rEFInd

Tags: linux, windows, boot, windows-update

I have Windows 8 and I would like to update to Windows 10 as I have reserved the free update.

I have rEFInd installed to boot to Linux as well, will the update overwrite the boot manager? If so, will I have problems then reinstalling rEFInd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, updating will replace the boot manager but it will keep rEFInd files so it can be restored executing this in an administrator terminal:

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\refind\refind_x64.efi
```